# why is a tcp message not getting written to the transport in twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

server.py

```
 # This is the Twisted Fast Poetry Server, version 1.0

    import optparse, os

    from twisted.internet.protocol import ServerFactory, Protocol


    def parse_args():
        usage = """usage: %prog [options] poetry-file

    This is the Fast Poetry Server, Twisted edition.
    Run it like this:

      python fastpoetry.py <path-to-poetry-file>

    If you are in the base directory of the twisted-intro package,
    you could run it like this:

      python twisted-server-1/fastpoetry.py poetry/ecstasy.txt

    to serve up John Donne's Ecstasy, which I know you want to do.
    """

        parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage)

        help = "The port to listen on. Default to a random available port."
        parser.add_option('--port', type='int', help=help)

        help = "The interface to listen on. Default is localhost."
        parser.add_option('--iface', help=help, default='localhost')

        options, args = parser.parse_args()

        if len(args) != 1:
            parser.error('Provide exactly one poetry file.')

        poetry_file = args[0]

        if not os.path.exists(args[0]):
            parser.error('No such file: %s' % poetry_file)

        return options, poetry_file


    class PoetryProtocol(Protocol):

        def __init__(self, factory):
            self.factory = factory

        def connectionMade(self):
            self.factory.pushers.append(self)
            #self.transport.write("self.factory.poem")
            #self.transport.write(self.factory.poem)
            #self.transport.loseConnection()



    class PoetryFactory(ServerFactory):

        #protocol = PoetryProtocol


        def __init__(self, poem):
            self.poem = poem
            self.pushers = []#

        def buildProtocol(self, addr):
            return PoetryProtocol(self)



    def main():
        options, poetry_file = parse_args()

        poem = open(poetry_file).read()

        factory = PoetryFactory(poem)


        from twisted.internet import reactor

        port = reactor.listenTCP(options.port or 0, factory,
                                 interface=options.iface)

        print 'Serving %s on %s.' % (poetry_file, port.getHost())

        reactor.run()

        factory.pushers[0].transport.write("hey")#########why is this message not received on the client?




    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

I have created a list called pushers (in the factory) of the protocols, when a connection is made. When I try to write to it, the message doesnt arrive in the datareceived on the client side. why?

Answer (score 0):

You calling `factory.pushers[0].transport.write` right after running reactor but protocol instance added to factory pushers list only when client connected to your server

Uncomment second line in connectionMade handler if you want to write to client when connection established:

```
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.pushers.append(self)
        self.transport.write("hey")
```

Comment: How do I wait to run the -factory.pushers[0].transport.write("hey") line till connection is made?